# Create mysql trigger to update specific column after update row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to update the specific column in MySQL after any change occurred in a row.
I use below query to create trigger but when to change record data, an error happened.

trigger query:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_update AFTER UPDATE ON group_chat_message
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   UPDATE `group_chat_message` SET 
   `server_modified_at` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(NOW(), '-', ''),1,8),SUBSTRING(REPLACE(NOW(), ':', ''),12,8))
    WHERE id = NEW.id
    ;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[image: error when trigger executed.]
<sub>(source: [imohammadi.ir](https://imohammadi.ir/dl/Untitled.png))</sub>

Comment: The error message is quite explicit. You can in some triggers amend the NEW. values but that's all.

Comment: thanks for your replay, not data changed. @P.Salmon

Comment: Is there a trigger/triggers on `group_chat_message`?

Comment: Yes, I used code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger should be :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_update BEFORE UPDATE ON group_chat_message
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   SET NEW.`server_modified_at` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(NOW(), '-', ''),1,8),SUBSTRING(REPLACE(NOW(), ':', ''),12,8));
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So basically, you should trigger it BEFORE and not AFTER, and you don't need to create this UPDATE instruction in the trigger. Instead, just modify the NEW value of `server_modified_at` before updating the row

---

Note that, if the aim is to store the timestamp when a record is modified, you can create a column like this in your table :

```
server_modified_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and MySQL will set the current timestamp to your server_modified_at column automatically when the row is updated, you don't need a trigger for that.

Answer (score -1):

You should simply modify your `CREATE TABLE`-Statement:

What you need can be achieved without a trigger, by using `ON UPDATE` for Timestamps and/or DateTime columns:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  some columns,
  lastModified_ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  lastModified dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The fields will be set to `NOW()` everytime a row is modified (`ON UPDATE`) or created (`DEFAULT`).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html